# How to add show/hide action in rails forms only in the view template

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to rails and using to devise for authentication, what i want to accomplish is user privacy.

Meaning in edit form i want to add a toggle switch action for example 'Email field' to give the user the ability to show/hide fields in his profile but the form still displayed in the edit view.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <!-- Left menu links -->        
          <ul class="nav-item pl-0">
            <h4 class="nav-link disabled mb-0 text-dark font-weight-bold">Settings</h4>
            <%= link_to 'Personal information', "/users/edit", class: "nav-link text-dark font-weight-bold" %>
            <%= link_to 'Account settings', "/account/settings", class: "nav-link text-dark font-weight-bold" %>
            <%= link_to 'Password settings', "/account/passwords", class: "nav-link text-dark font-weight-bold" %>
            <%= link_to 'Security', "/account/security", class: "nav-link text-dark font-weight-bold" %>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Right from inputs -->
        <div class="col-sm-9 shadow-sm border border-dark p-3 mb-5 mx-3 mx-sm-0 mx-lg-0 mx-xl-0 bg-white rounded">

          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold  justify-content-start">First name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <%= f.input :first_name, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control w-100 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0", placeholder: "First name"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold  justify-content-start">Last name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <%= f.input :last_name, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control w-100 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0", placeholder: "Last name"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown-divider my-4"></div>
          <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold px-3 mb-4">Biography</label>
          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold  justify-content-start">About:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= f.input :about, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control w-100 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0", placeholder: "Write in few lines something about yourself and what you are passionate about"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown-divider mt-5 mb-4"></div>
          <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold px-3 mb-4">Career</label>
          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold  justify-content-start">Company:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= f.input :company, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control w-100 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0", placeholder: "Where do you work?"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold  justify-content-start">Job title:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= f.input :job_title, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control w-100 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0", placeholder: "Current working position?"} %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold  justify-content-start">School / University:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= f.input :school, label: false, input_html: { class: "form-control w-100 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0", placeholder: "Name of school or university"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Right update button -->
          <div class="form-inline justify-content-end py-2 px-3">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Update", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

i made a custom devise registration controller

```
app/controllers/registations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      set_flash_message_for_update(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email)
      bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name if sign_in_after_change_password?
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
      redirect_to session.delete(:return_to), alert: resource.errors.full_messages[0]

    end
  end


  def settings
      @user = current_user
      if @user
          render :settings
      else
          render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
       end 
  end

  def passwords
    @user = current_user
    if @user
      render :passwords
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end

  def security
    @user = current_user
    if @user
      render :security
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end  
end
```

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

```
routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/show'
  root 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  resources :user, only: [:show]
  devise_scope :user do 
    get 'accounts/settings', to: 'registrations#settings', as: :settings
    get 'accounts/passwords', to: 'registrations#passwords', as: :passwords
    get 'accounts/security', to: 'registrations#security', as: :security
  end 
end
```

Comment: Can you include your current code for your edit form?

Comment: @Doughtz Yes of course, i'm still new to the stack community and how to display images the link down below shows how the form looks .

Comment: Which javascript framework are you using? Just plain old Javascript or JQuery or something else? Or nothing yet?

Comment: the solution you are suggesting only takes effect in `show.html.erb` and what i want is to make a field either shown/hidden in `index.html.erb` where user information is displayed. i'm just using the standard rails 6 with webpacker

Comment: Oh okay. So you don’t want the input box filled. You want to hide the attribute that is displayed on a different page?

Comment: yes exactly, i have been searching around for 2 days and couldn't find a way to implement it.

Comment: So you want a button that hides multiple fields at once, or multiple buttons that hide one field each?

Comment: i think it's better to have multiple buttons for each field

Comment: Okay. Can you post the code for the page where you want the attributes hidden? I’ll update it so you can hide them with a button click. It’ll be very similar to my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks! could your please specify which code, because what i have done with devise registration edit.html.erb, i created custom routes and split the form into multiple small forms. i'll post the codes

Comment: Just the code for the page index.html.erb because that’s where you want to toggle the hide/show

Comment: there's only simple piece of html i'm experimenting with ` <div class="text-dark"> <%= @user.email %> </div>

Comment: Okay check out my answer now.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct since it worked for you?

Comment: it works but not the how i want it, i think i would need additional fields (Boolean) to toggle those options. They can be added to user model and displayed in the devise edit registration form. Then i can conditionally render fields within my views based on those booleans.

by the way when i try to mark answers as corret, i get this message : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: I see. You want to save that preference of the info being hidden?

Comment: yes i guess so, i would need to generate a migration to user model with type of boolean and the rest i don't know how to achieve especially the conditions .

Comment: You would just create a migration like you said. rails g migration AddHiddenFieldsToShop hide_email:boolean hide_name:boolean

Comment: Then use the button to update the user model with the change of the value

Comment: so how i can associate the new AddHiddenFieldsToUser(in my case) with the previous migration (AddExtraFieldsToUser) ?

Comment: What do you mean by associate them?

Comment: I thought that ill be needing only one field `is_visible:boolean` and then i have created a condition in the view :

`<% if @user.is_visible? %>
  <div class="text-dark"> <%= @user.email %> </div>
<% end %>` and it worked just fine as i wanted it to be, now all i need to do is implement your suggestion for all the fields that i want to make invisble. thank you so much !!

Comment: yeah just need to create Ajax to change hide/show when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do 3 things:

- Add a button with an onclick handler that allows the user to click on it to hide/show the field
- Add an ID to the div you are using to show the attribute
- Create a javascript function to show/hide that div

So add the button outside the div you are hiding and include the onclick

```
<%= button_tag "Hide/Show", :onclick => "hideInput()" %>
```

Then add the ID to the div you are hiding. In your case, do something like this. You can use any ID you want. Mine is just an example.

```
<div id="emailDisplayed" class="text-dark"> <%= @user.email %> </div>
```

Then you want to add the hideInput function in your javascript file. Preferably in `assets/javascripts/[file_name]`

```
function hideInput() {
  var emailDiv = document.getElementById("emailDisplayed");
  emailDiv.style.display === "block" ?  emailDiv.style.display = 'none' : emailDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Now when the user clicks on the button, it will hide/show your div that contains the user email.

Comment: thanks it works like a charm, is it only related to the current user or all users who visit the current user profile ?

Comment: It will work for whoever the user is that is visiting that page.

Comment: You can test it by creating another user and you will see that it works for that user also.

Comment: that gonna takes some time, my routes are missed up and haven't got around to get user path by id, i have a lot to learn about rails but thank you so much for your effort and valuable time !!

Comment: Sure thing! Good luck! If you could, please mark this answer as correct :)